# Eclipse Window Builder - Empty Design tab on Mac M1 Pro

Tags: eclipse, macos, apple-m1, windowbuilder, palette

I'm trying to use Eclipse and Window Builder to make an SWT project, but I have the following issue. The Design tab amb Palette options are empty amb blocked:

[Screenshot Empty Design tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaEUL.png)

The file compiles and executes well:

[Screenshot code compile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crjj5.png)

I have tried lots of different versions of JDK, Eclipse and WB. Currently, I have the following versions.

**Window Builder**

[Screenshot Window Builder version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAbZl.png)

**Eclipse version:** Version: 2022-12 M1 (4.26.0 M1)

**Java:** JDK 18

There aren't errors or warnings, only the issue explained above.

Could you help me?

Comment: I see you have already reported this on the Windowbuilder Github, you are more likely to get an answer there. Note that Eclipse 2022-12M1 is a milestone release only intended for testing and is already obsolete - you would probably be better reporting this against the current official 2022-09 release.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @greg-449. I have tried with 2022-09 version and I had the same problem. Also, I have tried different JDK and Window Builder versions. I hope that someone with Apple Silicon M1 chip could help me because I don't know what more I can try :) . Thanks again

Comment: Try it with a fresh workspace, running Eclipse with an included Java 17 and without this theme plugin since it tries to cheat the Eclipse open source license by patching Eclipse at runtime (or to be more precise via loadtime weaving). This can cause issues and slow down Eclipse. Please use Stack Overflow only for real question, not to report issues.

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse/windowbuilder/issues/339

Comment: Thank @howlger. I have tried without DarkTheme and Eclipse with Java 17 and nothing has changed. Now, I have Eclipse Version: 2022-09 (4.25.0) with Java 17 and the last version of WindowBuilder: https://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/latest/

Comment: See https://github.com/eclipse/windowbuilder/issues/339#issuecomment-1288082990